# Sql Server The connection is closed

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, sql-server-2012

I have a java spring app connected to a database under SQL Server 2012.
THis is the properties and the datasource i am using :

```
-datasource.initialSize=34

-datasource.minIdle=89

-datasource.maxIdle=233

-datasource.maxActive=377

-datasource.maxWait=50000

-datasource.abandonWhenPercentageFull=50

-datasource.jmxEnabled=true

-datasource.removeAbandoned=true

-datasource.removeAbandonedTimeout=120

-datasource.logAbandoned=true

-datasource.testOnBorrow=true

-datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=60000

-datasource.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=80000

-datasource.validationInterval=40000
```

and the datasource managed by spring :

```
 <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close" 

            p:driverClassName="${datasource.driverClass}"
            p:url="${datasource.url}"
            p:username="${datasource.user}"
            p:password="${datasource.pass}" 
            p:maxWait="${datasource.maxWait}" 
            p:minIdle="${datasource.minIdle}"
            p:maxIdle="${datasource.maxIdle}"
            p:maxActive="${datasource.maxActive}"

            p:jmxEnabled="${datasource.jmxEnabled}"
            p:removeAbandoned="${datasource.removeAbandoned}"
            p:removeAbandonedTimeout="${datasource.removeAbandonedTimeout}"
            p:logAbandoned="${datasource.logAbandoned}"
            p:testOnBorrow="${datasource.testOnBorrow}"
                 p:timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="${datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis}"
            p:minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="${datasource.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis}"
            p:validationInterval="${datasource.validationInterval}"
            p:abandonWhenPercentageFull="${datasource.abandonWhenPercentageFull}"
            p:validationQuery="SELECT 1" 
            p:jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState"
        />
```

I have got a process which send a lot JMS Messages. I get the same error message at various time saying that the The Connection is Closed in my JMS Listenner. Any idea why it closes the connection ?

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:585)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at com.spectrags.fundhive.interceptor.PerfInterceptor.invoke(PerfInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at com.spectrags.fundhive.business.api.messaging.WorkflowJmsListener$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$704b2c20.onMessage(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:746)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:684)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:651)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:315)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:253)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1150)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1142)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1039)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.commit(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:581)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:388)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.commit(SQLServerConnection.java:1936)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor150.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState.invoke(ConnectionState.java:152)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:70)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:70)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer.invoke(ResetAbandonedTimer.java:62)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.TrapException.invoke(TrapException.java:40)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.commit(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.commit(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:80)
    ... 24 more
```

EDIT 25 / 02 / 2016 : this is what i've implemented but it still doesn't work :

```
public class ConnectionJDBCInterceptor extends JdbcInterceptor {

    protected static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ConnectionJDBCInterceptor.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void reset(final ConnectionPool pool, final PooledConnection pooledConnection) {

        try {
            if (pooledConnection.getConnection().isClosed()) {
                ConnectionJDBCInterceptor.log.info("Closed connection in the pool is being reconnected");
                pooledConnection.reconnect();
            }
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            ConnectionJDBCInterceptor.log.error(e, "Error in JDBC Interceptor", e);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issues. In case of IOException, the sqlserver jdbc driver marks the connection as closed, but this is not detected by the pool. So the connection is returned in the pool, while unusable.
A work around to this is to write a new JDBCInterceptor for tomcatjdbc. The interceptor must when close is invoked, call "isClosed" on the underlying connection. If the underlying connection is closed, the interceptor must marked the PooledConnection as discarded.
Then configure your pool to use this interceptor.

Comment: Thanks, is that not the job of of the jdbc interceptor ResetAbandonnedTimeout  already ?

Comment: no, ResetAbandonnedTimeout job is about resetting the timeout that mark the connection as abandoned each time you execute a request on that connection

Comment: Do you have an example that could help me to start ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use Tomcat JDBC pool, then you can exclude it from project and that solves the issue with reconnect.

For gradle:

```
configurations.all {
  exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat', module: 'tomcat-jdbc' 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue and found a good explanation and solution to the problem [here](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/solved-jdbcconnectionexception-unable-to-acquire-jdbc-connection-with-hibernate-and-mysql)

Summarily, your database or application server (e.g JBoss) connection pool manager has invalidated some connections due to idle timeout settings either set by default or configured explicitly, meanwhile, hibernate's internal database connection pool manager has those connections as valid connections. Hence, when your application tries to reuse them, you get the connection closed error which is not cleared until you restart your application server.

To resolve, simply delegate hibernate connection pool management to a helper library called hibernate-c3p0 and follow an example configuration such as

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300" />
```

These properties are well explained in the link above and also [here](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-c3p0)